# Google mock compile error (error: ‘<function name>’ is not a type)

Tags: c++, googlemock

My actual code (class name changed, some cut, as it is company confidential, but there is only one compiler error, so what I cut should not be affecting things)

```
class Xyz
{
public:
   virtual void vPrintStatus() const;  
};
```

and its mock

```
class MockXyz : public Xyz
{
 public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(vPrintStatus,
            void());
};
```

Which gives me a compiler error : `error: ‘vPrintStatus’ is not a type`

#includes, etc are OK. The compiler is obviously finding `vPrintStatus`, as, if I change it to something undefined:

```
MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(independence,
                void());
```

I get `error: ‘independence’ has not been declared`.

So, the compiler finds `vPrintStatus` and appears to know its type (or, at least, what type it is not).

I am sure that I am following the syntax for `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0` - the mock macro shoudl be expecting a function name, not a type, as its first parameter.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that real code, copy-pasted from the file you're compiling?

Comment: It looks that `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0` is parsed as a member function name, not a macro, make sure the includes are correct

Comment: Also make sure `Xyz` has a virtual destructor.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - you were correct - there was a missing #include "gmock.h". Feel free to post that as answer. Sorry to waste everyone's time, but I have been banging my head against this for hours :-(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The below error message:

```
error: ‘vPrintStatus’ is not a type
```

indicates that `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(vPrintStatus, void());` was parsed by a compiler as a declaration of a member function, named `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0`, taking two parameters, one of *type* `vPrintStatus` (hence the error), and another being a function pointer type (`void(*)()` after adjustment). Clearly, this means that the definition of macro `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0` is not visible to the translation unit the mock declaration is part of. Make sure you have included `<gmock/gmock.h>` to that file.

Comment: FYI: I found that I got this same error when I tried to MOCK_METHOD11.  GMock doesn't support more than 10 parameters in a mocked method.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15539169/149212.

Comment: Got this error when tried to use StrictMock<MyMock> without using namespace testing; // there are several possible causes for that error

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issues and it turns out I was trying to use:

`MOCK_CONST_METHODO` instead of

`MOCK_CONST_METHOD0` (zero works much better the O)

Comment: Get yourself normal font (like Iosevka etc) or syntax aware editor/IDE